# How to properly initiate a child class by inheritance in python?

Tags: python, class, inheritance

The title is probably not quite precise-sorry. I am practicing python class and wrote something like this:

```
class parent():
    def __init__(self, lastname,eyecolor):
        print "Parent class initiated!"
        self.lastname=lastname
        self.eyecolor=eyecolor

    def show_info(self):
        print("PARENT CLASS INFO:")
        print ("Lastname is:  "+self.lastname)

class child(parent):
    like_to = ['crawl', 'laugh', 'eat']
    def __init__(self, lastname, eyecolor, n_toys=10):
        parent.__init__(self, lastname, eyecolor)
        self.n_toys=n_toys

    def show_info(self):
        print ("CHILD CLASS INFO:")
        print("Child has %d toys" % self.n_toys)
```

Then I did:

```
from utils import parent, child

father=parent('Jackson', 'black')
father.show_info()
son=child('Jackson','black')
son.show_info()
```

I basically followed a tutorial so above codes worked well. Then I realized that if I comment out the

```
parent.__init__(self, lastname, eyecolor)
```

line in the child class, the codes still works.

So, what does this line do exactly? What are the differences, if any, with or without this line?

Comment: It runs the code in `parent.__init__` using the current instance as `self`. Without it, `self.lastname` and `self.eyecolor` won't be defined

Comment: So it sounds like i have to use this line?

Comment: Well, it's just good form. if you want `child` to inherit `lastname` and `eyecolor`. You could just explicitely assign those values in `child` 's `__init__`

Comment: @user3768495 see the answer

Comment: It only "works" because you're not testing the case where it doesn't work.  If you try to do anything with `self.lastname`, it won't work.

Comment: @BrenBarn you are right! Now I understand when it won't work:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
parent.__init__(self, lastname, eyecolor)
```

The line calls the `super` method `__init__` and initializes the `lastname`and `eyecolor`

If you comment this line:

```
//parent.__init__(self, lastname, eyecolor)
```

then your object won't have members `lastname`and `eyecolor` and you cannot access these members.

**Explanation**

When this line is called:

```
parent.__init__(self, lastname, eyecolor)
```

The `__init__` method of `parent` class is called:

```
def __init__(self, lastname,eyecolor):
    print "Parent class initiated!"
    self.lastname=lastname   // initialize lastname
    self.eyecolor=eyecolor   // initialize eyecolor
```

Which will initialize members `lastname` and `eyecolor`.

But commenting the line will stop calling `__init__` method of `parent` class but still works without crashing.

But this won't work when you comment that line:

```
son=child('Jackson','black')
son.show_info()
print(son.lastname) // won't work because lastname is not initialized
print(son.eyecolor) // won't work because eyecolor is not initialized
```